# Alternatives to Cron

Tags: 12.04, server, apache2, php, cron

I'm doing a server running Ubuntu Server 12.04 and Apache. The users have continuous updates in the dinamic pages through a Java script, downloading JSON files through Ajax request to server. All the users need the same data provided by a PHP file from a secondary mySQL database. To reduce the server load I decided to update the JSON file each second and save them in the server providing them as static content (like a txt file). For this reason I need a solution to run a PHP or any other language script on the server every second.

For future necessity i can't implement a logic like: compile the JSON at the first request and keep them saved for the other requests in the same second.

I read about the CronTab in Ubuntu but it dont allow me to perform the code each second. I tought about changing the entire Cron code 'cause I can't find other solutions.

Someone know if there is any solution in Ubuntu or maybe in the Apache codes to do it?
I need something stable and reliable. Someone ever heard about a sistem to perform code on server without the necessity of requests; to manipulate data each second?

**Any suggestion is welcome even complex but for a reliable result!**

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you have said in the first two paragraphs, so I can't tell if there's a better solution (my instincts scream there should be).

To run a command at X-second intervals, there are many options, discussed in this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299704/run-command-every-second) and [this Unix & Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10646/repeat-a-unix-command-every-x-seconds-forever).

---

#### Execution of command a second after the previous command finishes

Simply put, use a script like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
while sleep 1
do
   # your commands
done
```

#### Execution of command a second after the previous command starts

Same as above, but you send the command to the background. This will result in overlapping command executions if the command takes longer than 1 second to complete.

```
#! /bin/bash
while sleep 1
do
   (# your commands )&
done
```

---

Now, to make sure that the script is running, use [an Upstart job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/):

```
description "a good description"
start on runlevel [!016]
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn

exec /path/to/the/above/script
```

Save this is to a `.conf` file in `/etc/init`, such as `/etc/init/some-job.conf`. Now you can start the script with:

```
service some-job start
```

The `respawn` option will make Upstart restart the script if it ever exits (it shouldn't).